# Custom fields showing on other posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress & Advanced Custom Fields and I have one field called "show_additional_information", which if set to "Yes" should show an extra subset of information.  However, when those fields are populated, they are displaying on top of one another on all record-of-the-month post types.  I think I need to somehow set it to pull from only the displayed post but am unsure on how to do so.  Any help would be much appreciated

```
<?php query_posts(array(
 'post_type' => 'record-of-the-month', // post type with custom fields for display
 'meta_key' => 'show_additional_information', // custom field to display extra info
 'meta_compare' => '=',
 'meta_value' => 'Yes',
)
); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<section class='bg-cover invert-section triple-margin-bottom' style='background-image: url(<?php the_field('background_image_2'); ?>);'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-2'></div>
      <div class='col-md-8 text-center'>
    <?php the_field('press_quote'); ?>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-2'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class='padding-top double-padding-bottom double-margin-bottom border-bottom'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-1'></div>
       <div class='col-md-10 double-padding-right'>
    <?php the_field('artist_bio'); ?>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-1'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<?php endwhile;  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What type of custom field are you using? If you were using the true/false selector you could use:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'record-of-the-month',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_name',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '=='
        )
    )
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

//
```

Either way, try using WP_query over query_posts

Comment: Thanks for the quick info, Johnny.  Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working.  It's still showing the fields from all posts.  It's a select box custom field via Advanced custom fields (values set to 0 : No; 1 : Yes). It displays fine if there's not query. But if there's nothing in those fields, then there's a big white space.  Just need that white space to be eliminated if there is no info populated in those extra fields.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by putting separate if statements before the individuals fields (see code below).

```
<?php if( $field = get_field('background_image_2') ): ?>
<section class='bg-cover invert-section triple-margin-bottom' style='background-image: url(<?php the_field('background_image_2'); ?>);'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-2'></div>
       <div class='col-md-8 text-center'>
    <?php the_field('press_quote'); ?>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-2'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( $field = get_field('artist_bio') ): ?>
<section class='padding-top double-padding-bottom double-margin-bottom border-bottom'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-1'></div>
      <div class='col-md-10 double-padding-right'>
        <?php the_field('artist_bio'); ?>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-1'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```